# Update a constraint in postgresql 9.1 database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to change "on delete restrict" to "on delete cascade": how can i do it ?

```
ALTER TABLE T1
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_T1 FOREIGN KEY (id1)
  REFERENCES T2 (id1) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm quite sure you need to drop and recreate it -- there is, to the best of my knowledge, no `alter table alter constraint ...` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to drop it and recreate it.

```
ALTER TABLE T1 DROP CONSTRAINT fk_T1;

ALTER TABLE T1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_T1 FOREIGN KEY (id1)
REFERENCES T2 (id1) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```